# How to do character matching in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, ocr, image-recognition

I am trying to develop a character matching application which will take an image from a camera and match it with a provided image template. So far I have tried `matchShapes` of contours which is not working correctly on characters, it's working fine for simple shapes. I tried using `matchTemplate` but that's also not working correctly if I change size, font or rotation of character written in image captured from camera and try matching it with template image.

I am now thinking I need to do feature extraction after segmenting the camera image in sets and compare these sets with a feature set of reference images. Can anyone please give me a starting off direction or suggestion.

For example, this is an image from camera

[image]

and I need to find a template image

[image]

Comment: Being new to OpenCV and OCR, you should start with a simpler example. Handwritten, scaled, rotated characters is certainly not the easiest task. MatchTemplate will work a lot better with printed characters and in a controlled environment (limited or known scale/rotation).

Answer (score 2):

I must stress that I am no expert at optical character recognition so please do a thorough research on your end as well. Following are two links that might help you achieve your goal using character feature sets:

http://blog.damiles.com/2008/11/basic-ocr-in-opencv/
http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_knn/py_knn_opencv/py_knn_opencv.html